# Ошибка при запросе

Tags: c#

Осуществляю запросы таким образом

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = method;

        if (method == "POST") {
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
            request.ContentType = content_type;
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in headers) {
            request.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        request.Timeout = timeout;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = auto_redirect;
        request.CookieContainer = cookie_container;

        HttpWebResponse response;
        try {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        } catch (WebException ex) {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            if (response == null)
                throw;
        }

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Часто при использовании прокси на последнюю строку выдает ошибку

```
The response ended prematurely, with at least 677 additional bytes expected
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, смысл всего этого кода, если в итоге вы тупо читаете строку? Вот смысл вам открывать Stream и прочее? Это ведь все можно сделать одной строкой... К тому же, прочитайте документацию про `WebRequest`, вы там увидите, что он устарел в C#, лучше использовать замену.

Comment: Да, согласен, что устарел. Я переписал на HttpClient, там тоже возникает эта же ошибка

Comment: Ну, значит надо делать минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который позволит нам воспроизвести проблему. А вообще, на сколько я знаю, указанная вами ошибка является "поверхностной", это означает, что там есть внутренняя ошибка, которая более точно говорит в чем проблема. Ну а проблема сама скорей всего не в коде, а на стороне сервера, ну или прокси, которые попросту рвут вам соединение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The response ended prematurely, with at least 677 additional bytes expected
```

Означает, что пришел ответ, содержащий в HTTP заголовке `Content-Length`, значение которого больше на 677 байт, чем было реально получено данных, после чего отвечающая сторона принудительно закрыла соединение.

Здесь нечего исправлять со стороны вашего кода, он не является источником данный ошибки. Единственное, что можно сделать, это попытаться все-таки прочитать данные, которые пришли и погасить исключение. Корректность данных при подобных ошибках, конечно же, не гарантируется.

Источником проблемы, как уже подмечено выше в комментариях, является либо ошибка в реализации сервера, либо сетевые проблемы при передаче данных.

Comment: А какой класс посоветуете использовать для создания http-запросов в C#? Особенно, если запросы будут выполняться в нескольких потоках?

Comment: @Александр `HttpClient`, альтернатив то как бы особо и нет. Он асинхронный, ему не нужны потоки, он и так параллельно заточен работать. Поизучайте асинхронное программирование `async/await`. Информации полинтернета.

Comment: А что можете сказать про HttpClientFactory? Подойдет для многопоточности? @aepot

Comment: @Александр фабрика нужна для более сложных задач, например в серверах, если у вас простое клиентское приложение, то одного клиента достаточно. Один клиент может выполнять много запросов за раз, он и так многопоточный, если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Чтобы избежать утечки соединений нужно использовать один экземпляр HttpClient для запросов, хорошо ли это будет работать, если при многопотоке запросы направляются на разные url? И на каком уровне нужно создать этот экземпляр, на каждый поток или один на все потоки? @aepot

Comment: @Александр будет нормально работать. И вы путаете асинхронность и многопоточность. Изучите разницу.

Comment: Большое спасибо)